# no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am using the ubuntu 14.04, and installed CUDA toolkit 6.5 and driver (GeForce GTX 550), It used to work for me, but for some reason, I can't run load the nvidia module now.

Here is some info on the nvidia module:

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidia
  modprobe: FATAL : Module nvidia not found.

$lspci | grep -i nvidia 
VAG compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF116 [GeForce GTX 550 Ti]

$ nvcc -V
nvcc:NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright 2005 - 2014 NVIDIA Corporation
Cuda compilation tools, release 6.5, v6.5.12
```